# Columns in Response tab are strange widths

Tags: bug, profile-page

The user column of the Revisions tabs of the Responses tab of the profile is way narrow.  (The rest of the tabs of Responses aren't much better.)

[image]

This was taken with Google Chrome - Version 80.0.3987.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: A few days ago I had the exact same problem with the latest Firefox. The situation is somewhat better now, but still doesn't look quite right.

Comment: [meta.se]: [Line/word wrapping in revision history and responses tab (and probably other places)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342171)

Comment: The post on [meta.se] mentioned in the previous comment is now marked ([meta-tag:status-completed]).

Comment: It is completed indeed!  \o/